# Share image instagram using UIActivityViewController swift 3/4 have alert controller error

Tags: ios, swift, image, instagram, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have search in stackoverflow using swift 3/4 to share image instagram using UIActivityViewController. But when I want to share image then click instagram logo, then there is alert that says "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again. Is there anyway to solve this ?

```
            let image = UIImage(named: "instaIcon.png")
            let objectsToShare: [AnyObject] = [ image! ]
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

            activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook, UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.assignToContact, UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard,
            UIActivityType.mail, UIActivityType.markupAsPDF, UIActivityType.message, UIActivityType.openInIBooks,
            UIActivityType.postToFacebook, UIActivityType.postToFlickr, UIActivityType.postToTencentWeibo,
            UIActivityType.postToTwitter, UIActivityType.postToVimeo, UIActivityType.postToWeibo]

            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I had to amend the code to Swift 4 syntax but it works ok to my Instagram App.  How big is the image you are trying to send ?  With a very large image it may fail, and you may want to downside or compress the image before attaching.

Comment: @rbaldwin I think the problem would be in the UI Image. maybe that's why the sharing does not do anything